# Life cycle of cordova application

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am using visual studio 2015 for cordova app development. I want to know how the onDeviceReady function in the index.js gets called when we load index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Apache Cordova documentation that describes how onDeviceReady works:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html